Where should default values for model attributes be set in a Spring Boot application: Controller, Service, or Model layer?
In a Spring Boot application, I want to set default values for certain attributes or columns in my model. I’m trying to figure out the best layer to handle this for the sake of clean, maintainable, and extensible code.

Should defaults be set at the controller level when processing requests?
Or would it make more sense to handle this in the service layer, where business logic is typically placed?
Alternatively, should defaults be set directly within the model itself?

My primary concern is maintaining clean, extensible, and easily maintainable code as the application grows.
What are the best practices and potential implications for each approach?

What do you mean by "column"? A database column?

attribute in model

I advice to [edit] the post and add the clarification.

updated the question properly. Apologies for being lazy at the first place :)

As I commented in the answer below, there’s no definitive approach. It’s a design question. I personally preference to add it either to the entity or to use a builder pattern with default values and make my entities final. Lombok is a nice way to achieve this

What do you mean by defaults for column?
If you are asking about default values for database column you should make it constraint.
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_DATA
(
COL_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
IS_TEST_COLUMN INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO DUMMY_DATA(COL_NAME) VALUES('TEST');

SELECT * FROM DUMMY_DATA;

In above example if you just insert data in column col_name then is_test_column will automatically be 0. You can also set default value for col_name
Although if you don't want to set default values using this way then setting default values on service layer makes sense.
Service layer sets values -> values go to DAO layer -> Model gets populated and transaction gets committed on DAO layer. Even if you are asking about attribute/field of DTO still service layer makes more sense. Your Bean, DTO or whatever just gets populated on service layer and controller will just forward response from service layer to the client.

There’s no definitive answer, it depends on preferences. Database, Model layer or service layer are all valid approaches. There’s no pattern that would disallow this, it’s more a design question. Also there’s no approach that makes “more sense” it all depends on the use case
